# prevUntil('.class') and nextUntil('.class') don't appear do be working for me, selecting beyond the designated element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$target.after($tq.clone()); 
var $newElement = $target.next();    
$newElement.prevUntil('.question.edit:eq(' + tqIndex + ')')
           .each(function () {
var $elm = $(this).find('input.position');
var val = parseInt($elm.attr('value')); $elm.attr('value', (val - 1));
$tq.detach();
```

I am using this to move around some elements and update a field display an integer with their position. Say if I clone `$tq` which is lets say `$('.question.edit:eq(3)')`  and insert the html after `$('.question.edit:eq(6)')` I then want to subtract 1 from each elements position field between the newly inserted clone of `$tq`, being `$('.question.edit:eq(7)')` and until and not including `$tq` which is `$('.question.edit:eq(3)')` to update the position/count. `$tq` is then detached and the count is correct.

What I am seeing is the `prevUntil()` and `nextUntil()` will not stop at `('.question.edit:eq('+ tqIndex + ')')` and will effect elements lower than the one at the specified index count, in fact all of them until parent.

Maybe I am just not passing the `tqIndex` value correctly, but it seems fine.

Comment: I think it would be more understandable if you replace the first 2 lines by that: `var $newElement = $tq.clone().insertAfter($target);`

Answer (score 2):

[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) matches the element at specified index *within a set*. It is not designed to be used with `prevUntil()` and `nextUntil()`, which apply a selector to individual elements.

Try using [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) instead:

```
$newElement.prevUntil(".question.edit:nth-child(" + (tqIndex + 1) + ")")
```

Note that `:nth-child()` is one-based whereas `:eq()` is zero-based, so you have to add `1` to `tqIndex` to obtain the appropriate index.

Comment: This works for IE10 and FireFox only. Does not work in Chrome for some reason. See: http://jsfiddle.net/hp7Cz/25/ and try to move Question 2 to spot number 3. The code in the fiddle is only valid for moving down.